# Node.js - Find variable in files and build object out of them

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Didn't really know how to explain this. Essentially, I have a directory stucture:

```
src/
    modules/
        clients/
            i18n/
                en-US.ts

        tasks/
            i18n/
                en-US.ts
```

Now each of those .ts files looks the same:

```
export default {
    "Key1": "The value",
    "Key2": "The value 2",

}
```

But the files will of course have different key names and values.

Now, I need to precompile all of these files into a single index.ts that looks like this:

```
messages: {
    'en-US': {
        "Key1": "....",
        ....
    }
}
```

At the moment, what I have is really crap. I basically have these language files as "txt" files with the "contents" of the object

```
    'Key1': 'Some test',
```

and I build the index.ts file by first writing all the code up to the ": {" where the messages need to go, then I read those txt files and input their contents in, and then finally I close up the object.

Really, I want to be able to actually read the export of these actual ts files and concat the value into a variable which I later write into the index.ts file..

Is this possible?

Comment: Is the list of files dynamic?

Comment: Yes, there could be any number of those modules - the looping logic is not an issue. It's more the fact that I want to read the variable rather than just the content of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure might be more complex but here's a simple version of a file import:

```
import { basename } from 'node:path'
async function buildMessages(file_list) {
  const messages = {}
  for (const file_path of file_list) {
    const file_label = basename(file_path, '.ts') // build specific
    if (!messages[file_label]) messages[file_label] = {}
    const file_messages = await import(file_path)
    Object.assign(messages[file_label], file_messages.default)
  }
  return messages
}
```

The precompile step is easier with `deno` or `ts-node` where you can use the typescript filenames directly. Running it from compiled TS depends on the TS build setup as the file extensions and imports can vary with tsconfig options.

```
const built_file_list = [ './a.ts', './b.ts', './c.ts' ]
const messages = await buildMessages(built_file_list)
```

This could also run in plain node.js if the "build file list" task created a symlink to, or copy of, all the files as `x.mjs` and you can ensure the language files remain plain JS ESM compliant.

Then construct code for simple data types via JSON:

```
const code = `const messages = ${JSON.stringify(messages, undefined, 2))}`
//>>>
const messages = {
  "a": {
    "key": "aa",
    "key2": "ab"
  },
  "b": {
    "key3": "ba",
    "key": "bcw"
  },
  "c": {
    "key4": "ca",
    "key5": "cd"
  }
}
```

If the target for `index.ts` is a Node environment, you could write the messages data to a JSON file and import that back into `index.ts`. Using a JSON import requires some typescript build shenanigans to get setup.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time on this @Matt, I'll give this a go later tonight and let you know the outcome. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. This kind of logic should get it done. I haven't really tested it, but following it, should get you to what you want.

```js
let messages = {}
let module_folder_directory = "some_directory"
fs
  .readdirSync(module_folder_directory)
  .forEach((module)=>{
    fs
    .readdirSync(path.join(module_folder_directory, module, "i18n"))
    // Assuming there's only one file in the folder, you could just access the first element in the array.
    .forEach((file)=>{
      messages[file] = require(path.join(module_folder_directory, module, "i18n", file))
    })
  })
```

You could read more on the file system [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).